# Pygame ValueError: invalid color argument problem

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a rainbow of rectangles with pygame but I get a problem saying "ValueError: invalid color argument"

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

width = 400
height = 400
window_size = (width , height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)

colour = pygame.color.Color('#646400')

row = 0
done = False
while not done:
    increment = 255 / 100
    while row <= height:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, (0, row, width, row + increment))
        pygame.display.flip()
        if colour[2] + increment < 255:
            colour[2] += increment
        row += increment

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change this, `colour = pygame.color.Color('#646400')`
because it will be easier to go with the RGB colors in a `list`. change it to this:

```
colour = [0,0,100]
```

or to any kind of color you want maybe mix them to get the rainbow as result. This is what I would do. The result of the code is a gradient blue color. But as I mentioned before you can change it. But remember you cannot use a `tuple`! Because the aren't mutable.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to just use a `tuple` of RGB values for the color:

```
color = (0x64, 0x64, 0x00)  # equal to #646400
```

And then just pass it as the second argument to `draw.rect()` like you've already done:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (0, row, width, row + increment))
```

Answer (score 0):

As many others have suggested, PyGame does not support HTML-notation colour strings.

But it's fairly simple to convert these:

```
# Convert HTML-like colour hex-code to integer triple tuple
# E.g.: "#892da0" -> ( 137, 45, 160 )
def hexToColour( hash_colour ):
    """Convert a HTML-hexadecimal colour string to an RGB triple-tuple"""
    red   = int( hash_colour[1:3], 16 )
    green = int( hash_colour[3:5], 16 )
    blue  = int( hash_colour[5:7], 16 )
    return ( red, green, blue )

...

colour = hexToColour( '#646400' )
```

It's not normally necessary to convert these into a `Color` object to use them.